# How to extract specific sequences from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

This question is related to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212370/how-to-filter-rows-based-on-the-sequence-related-constraint). Given the following dataframe:

```
df = 
    ID   TYPE   VD_0   VD_1   VD_2   VD_3   VD_4   VD_5
    1    ABC    V1234  aaa    bbb    456    123    564
    2    DBC    456    A45    aaa    V1234  bbb    564
    3    ABD    456    V1234  bbb    ccc    456    123
    4    ABD    ccc    aaa    123    V1234  SSW    123
```

There is the following list of target values of `VD_0`-`VD_5`:

```
myList = [V1234,456,A45]
```

I want to get only those rows in `df` that have 2 or more "sequencial" occurances of values from `myList` in columns `VD_0`-`VD_5`, **BUT it is allowed to have any other values between them** (any other that do not belong to `myList`). For example, these allowed values might be `aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc`, etc.

The result should be this one:

```
result = 
    ID   TYPE   Col_0   Col_1   Col_2 
    1    ABC    V1234   456
    2    DBC    456     A45     V1234
    3    ABD    456     V1234   456
```

**In the `result` I want to display only values from `myList` in columns `Col_`, while ignoring the rest of values.**

The following code works fine, but it does not take into account that it is allowed to have in between any values that do not appear in `myList`:

```
subset = df.filter(like='VD_')

df[subset.isin(myList).rolling(2, axis=1).sum().max(axis=1)>=2]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need check lengths of `True` values in columns and rows of `DataFrame` by [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) of `boolean DataFrame`.

Then is problem for selecting columns, so need add missing columns from `df.columns` by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.reindex.html) with `fill_values=True`:

```
myList = ['V1234','456','A45']
subset = df.filter(like='VD_')

subset1 = subset.isin(myList)
mask1 = subset1.sum(axis=1) >= 2
print (mask1)

0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool

mask2 = subset1.sum() >= 2
print (mask2)
VD_0     True
VD_1     True
VD_2    False
VD_3     True
VD_4    False
VD_5    False
dtype: bool

print (mask2.reindex(df.columns, fill_value=True))
ID       True
TYPE     True
VD_0     True
VD_1     True
VD_2    False
VD_3     True
VD_4    False
VD_5    False
dtype: bool
```

```
print (df.loc[mask1, mask2.reindex(df.columns, fill_value=True)])
   ID TYPE   VD_0   VD_1   VD_3
0   1  ABC  V1234    aaa    456
1   2  DBC    456    A45  V1234
2   3  ABD    456  V1234    ccc
```

Comment: Is it possible to show only values from `myList` in the final result (similar to my example). Also, could you please explain why you use `sum(axis=1) > 1`, but not `sum(axis=1) >= 2`

Comment: It looks to do what I need, but in my real dataset I have more than 100 columns `VD_`. Is it possible that the final result does not show `aaa`, `ccc` and all other values that are not in `myList`?

Comment: I mean: those columns that have False should be not shown, like in my example in the question.

Comment: I will publish this doubt as another question, because actually I have some more related doubts.

Comment: This is the link to the relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273170/how-to-filter-out-the-values-from-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way.

```
In [903]: df.apply(lambda x: [y for y in x if y in myList], axis=1)
Out[903]:
0         [V1234, 456]
1    [456, A45, V1234]
2    [456, V1234, 456]
3              [V1234]
dtype: object

In [904]: s = df.apply(lambda x: [y for y in x if y in myList], axis=1)

In [905]: s[s.apply(len) >= 2]
Out[905]:
0         [V1234, 456]
1    [456, A45, V1234]
2    [456, V1234, 456]
dtype: object

In [906]: s[s.apply(len) >= 2].apply(pd.Series)
Out[906]:
       0      1      2
0  V1234    456    NaN
1    456    A45  V1234
2    456  V1234    456
```