# How to filter out the values from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

From the given dataframe:

```
df = 
    ID   TYPE   VD_0   VD_1   VD_2   VD_3   VD_4   VD_5   Val_0   Val_1   Val_2   Val3   Val_4   Val_5
    1    ABC    V1234  aaa    bbb    456     123   aaa    0       0       0       1       0      0
    2    DBC    456    A45    aaa    V1234   bbb   564    0       0       0       0       0      0
    3    ABD    V1234  V1234  bbb    ccc     456   123    0       0       0       0       0      1
    4    ABD    ccc    RTY    SSW    123     ccc   123    0       0       0       0       1      0
```

I want to select only those values of columns `VD_` that are in this list:

```
myList = head + tail
```

**Rule 1:** Besides this, the selected rows should start from the following values:

```
head = ["V1234","RTY"]
```

**Rule 2:** and should have the corresponding `Val_` equal to 0 for the value coming right after `head` and belonging to `tail`:

```
tail = ["456","123"]
```

The result should be this one (for example, the row with `ID` 1 is not included because it has `Val_3` equal to 1, which means that Rule 2 is not fulfilled):

```
result = 
    ID   TYPE   Col_1  Col_2   Col_3   Col_4   Val_1   Val_2   Val_3   Val_4
    3    ABD    V1234  V1234   456     123     0       0       0       1    
    4    ABD    RTY    123     123             0       0       0
```

Comment: why in second row in output are only two `0` and not four `0` ?

Comment: @jezrael: Because there are 3 values `RTY    123     123` in `Col_`. In particular, `RTY` corresponds to `VD_1` in the initial `df`, then `123` -> `VD_3`, `123`->`VD_5`. Then the values of `Val_` are taken correspondingly from `Val_1`, `Val_3` and `Val_5`.